# How to get predicted probabilities on validation sets (in K-fold cv) by Least Squares SVM through R's Caret Package?

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I am using `R`'s `caret` package for binary classification. I tried using Least Squares Support Vector Machine with Polynomial Kernel (`lssvmRadial` as method in `train` function) as follows :

```
least_suqares_svm_model <- train(x = input_predictors,
                                 y = input_labels, 
                                 method = "lssvmRadial", 
                                 trControl = myTrainControl, 
                                 tuneLength = 1, 
                                 preProcess = c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"))
```

I have set `classProbs = TRUE` in `myTrainControl` function. But the `pred` dataframe looks like follows :

```
> head(least_suqares_svm_model$pred)
  pred obs rowIndex      sigma Resample
1    0   0        1 0.01960077   Fold01
2    1   1        6 0.01960077   Fold01
3    1   0       10 0.01960077   Fold01
4    0   0       16 0.01960077   Fold01
5    1   1       31 0.01960077   Fold01
6    1   1       32 0.01960077   Fold01
```

How can I get class probabilites as well (so that I can compute `roc`, etc.)?

Comment: isn't there an argument in the predict function that helps in selecting the response type? Say example, response = "class"/ "prob". Please share a small data set which would help in reproducing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered definitively.

I'm guessing that you gave it binary indicators for the outcome so it is actually fitting a regression model. Give the outcome as a factor.